printing sub-bullets from a docx file in Python
I have a docx and would like to extract the whole file. In the file, it contains this format:
1.Hypothesis
1.1 lots of random text here
1.5 more random text here
1.6 [random table]

Procedure:

2.1 ramdom text here
2.2 more random text here
2.5 moreeee random text here
When I run my code below, it prints out the paragraphs and contents of the tables but not the sub-bullets. How can i print out the sub-bullets in my code?
Below is my code:
file_path = r'C:/insert path here/' 

import docx

def read_docx(file_path):
    doc = docx.Document(file_path)
    
    # Initialize lists to hold paragraph and table data
    paragraphs = []
    tables = []

    # Iterate over paragraphs
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        paragraphs.append(paragraph.text)

    # Iterate over tables
    for table in doc.tables:
        table_data = []
        for row in table.rows:
            row_data = []
            for cell in row.cells:
                row_data.append(cell.text)
            table_data.append(row_data)
        tables.append(table_data)

    return paragraphs, tables


paragraphs, tables = read_docx(file_path)


print("Paragraphs:")
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    print(paragraph)

print("\nTables:")
for table in tables:
    for row in table:
        print(row)

I'm stuck, please help.
